# YouTube comments extractor infinite loop if there is too many comments

Tags: python, loops, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I coded a script to extract and store YouTube's video comments in a file given the id of the video. If the video has less than 10-15 comments there are no problems and the script works fine, but when there are more it goes in an infinite loop and I can't figure out why.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build 
import os
api_key = '...'

def video_comments(video_id): 
    # empty file for storing comments
    outputFile = open("comments_"+video_id+".txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')

    # empty dictionnary to store the data
    commentsDict = []

    # empty list for storing reply 
    replies = [] 

    # creating youtube resource object 
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', 
                    developerKey=api_key) 

    # retrieve youtube video results 
    video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list( 
    part='snippet,replies', 
    videoId=video_id 
    ).execute() 

    # iterate video response 
    while video_response: 
        
        # extracting required info 
        # from each result object 
        for item in video_response['items']: 
            # Extracting comments 
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'] 
            commentEntrie = {"comment": comment, 'replies': []}
            
            # counting number of reply of comment 
            replycount = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount'] 

            # if reply is there 
            if replycount>0: 
                
                # iterate through all reply 
                for reply in item['replies']['comments']: 
                    
                    # Extract reply 
                    reply = reply['snippet']['textDisplay'] 
                    
                    # Store reply is list 
                    replies.append(reply) 
                    commentEntrie['replies'].append(reply)
                    
            # print comment with list of reply 
            print(comment, replies, end = '\n\n')
            outputFile.write("%s" % comment)
            outputFile.write("%s\n" % replies)
            commentsDict.append(commentEntrie)
            # empty reply list 
            replies = [] 

        # Again repeat 
        if 'nextPageToken' in video_response: 
            video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list( 
                    part = 'snippet,replies', 
                    videoId = video_id 
                ).execute() 
        else: 
            break
    outputFile.close()
    print(commentsDict)

# Enter video id 
video_id = "aDHYbM9OqUc" 

# Call function 
video_comments(video_id)
```

I can provide two video id, this one `LVgKlfw4DHc` works fine but this one end in an infinite loop `aDHYbM9OqUc`
Any ideas ?

[EDIT] I feel like the `nextPageToken` is always here and it goes in infinite while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop `while video_response:` goes infinite because of this piece of code:

```py
if 'nextPageToken' in video_response: 
    video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list( 
        part = 'snippet,replies', 
        videoId = video_id 
    ).execute() 
else: 
    break
```

If the first `video_response` contains the property `nextPageToken`, then the call to `CommentThreads.list` that's inside the loop **is exactly the same** as the one that's outside the loop. Thus, by this second call, you're getting *exactly* the same `video_response` as the one obtained from the previous call.

The correct implementation would be:

```py
if 'nextPageToken' in video_response: 
    video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list( 
        pageToken = video_response['nextPageToken'],
        part = 'snippet,replies', 
        videoId = video_id 
    ).execute() 
else: 
    break
```

Since you're using the Google's [APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client), the [pythonic way](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/pagination.html) of implementing [result set pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) on the [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) API endpoint looks like the one below:

```py
request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
    part = 'snippet,replies', 
    videoId = video_id 
)

while request:
    response = request.execute()

    for item in response['items']:
        ...

    request = youtube.commentThreads().list_next(
        request, response)
```

It is this simple due to the way the Python client library is implemented: there's no need to handle explicitly the API response object's property [`nextPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#nextPageToken) and the API request parameter `pageToken` at all.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer ! I appreciate the details thank you !